# Size of db2 database

Tags: db2, udb-db2

How can I get the size of my UDB DB2 version 9.1 database? I tried firing getdbconfig from the command prompt. It gives all the configuration but not the size.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a TechNote on IBM's support site:

**[How to calculate the size of a DB2 database](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21231144)**

> If you want to calculate the size and
>   maximum capacity of your database, you
>   can use the procedure
>   `GET_DBSIZE_INFO`. This procedure
>   first appeared in DB2 Universal
>   Database™ (DB2 UDB) Version 8.2.

To execute this procedure you should follow these three steps:

1. Connect to the database for which you want to know the size and maximum capacity.
2. Execute the procedure `GET_DBSIZE_INFO`.
3. Close the connection.

Here is the syntax of the procedure:

```
 db2 call GET_DBSIZE_INFO (?,?,?,refresh-window)
```

The first three  parameters are output parameters, and the refresh-window is an input parameter of type INTEGER that specifies the number of minutes until the cached values for database size and capacity are to be refreshed.

Refer to [this documentation link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0011863.htm) for examples of the output from this procedure in DB2 UDB Version 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [script here](http://www.db2ude.com/?q=node/118) which has been tested in 9.1 and, according to the author:

> will calculate the size of a DB2 LUW
>   database on a UNIX server using UNIX
>   commands that will give you a more
>   accurate measure of the space used by
>   the database. This script also stores
>   this information in an operational
>   table that you may use as part of your
>   DBA Monitoring Dash Board to help you
>   monitor and manage space in relation
>   to growth trends.

Answer (score 0):

The **GET_DBSIZE_INFO** procedure calculates the database size and maximum capacity.
The calculated values are returned as procedure output parameters and are cached in the **SYSTOOLS.STMG_DBSIZE_INFO** table.
The procedure caches these values because the calculations are costly.
The SYSTOOLS.STMG_DBSIZE_INFO table is created automatically the first time the procedure executes.
If there are values cached in the SYSTOOLS.STMG_DBSIZE_INFO table and they are current enough, as determined by the snapshot-timestamp and refresh-window values, these cached values are returned.
If the cached values are not current enough, new cached values are calculated, inserted into the SYSTOOLS.STMG_DBSIZE_INFO table and returned, and the snapshot-timestamp value is updated.

The below returns the database size and capacity using a refresh window of 0 minutes. The database size and capacity will be recalculated immediately.

**`CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, 0)`**

```
Value of output parameters
--------------------------
Parameter Name  : SNAPSHOTTIMESTAMP
Parameter Value : 2004-02-29-18.33.34.561000

Parameter Name  : DATABASESIZE
Parameter Value : 22302720

Parameter Name  : DATABASECAPACITY
Parameter Value : 4684859392

Return Status = 0
```

You may query the systools.stmg_dbsize_info directly to get the results as well.

> **db2 "select db_size, db_capacity from systools.stmg_dbsize_info"**
>
> **db2 "select db_size/1073741824 as SIZE_GB, db_capacity/1073741824 as
>   CAPACITY_GB from systools.stmg_dbsize_info"**

```
db2 "select db_size, db_capacity from systools.stmg_dbsize_info"

DB_SIZE              DB_CAPACITY
-------------------- --------------------
       1089248165888        1342416097280

  1 record(s) selected.

db2 "select db_size/1073741824 as SIZE_GB, db_capacity/1073741824 as CAPACITY_GB from systools.stmg_dbsize_info"

SIZE_GB              CAPACITY_GB
-------------------- --------------------
                1014                 1250

  1 record(s) selected.
```